# ElasticSearch: delete shard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my index distributed by customer: 1 customer <-> 1 shard

When customer is deleted I want to delete the whole shard related to corresponding customer and will be excellent if I can do this repdily. Is it possible to delete whole shard directly? Are there are any alternatives to delete large amount of data from elasticsearch?

Comment: How did you achieved such a distribution? (1 customer = 1 shard)
ES does not allows you to change the number of shards after you have  created an index. You can delete documents but shards will stay there.

Comment: Thats true as @shyos told. You can delete documents but shards will stay there. Please refer to my answer below for the solution. And I guess the OP has used routing with aliases. But, even with that, all you can make sure is documents from an alias stay in a single shard. That doesn't mean 1 customer = 1 shard. Not sure how he achieved that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer might have some thing in common an id or something...You can use the delete by query api to do the same based on the id criteria.

Please have a look at the following link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/docs-delete-by-query.html

Using this you can delete all docs which has a common id (in your case it can be customer id) in the index.

I hope the id is indexed as well.

Comment: Got it already. Deletion by query works very well, even for large amount of data

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Changed the link. Thanks for the intimation @kjw0188